# SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet : as relation does not exist

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, sequence

I am getting an exception with spring boot with postgres DB when using a sequence generator.

Below is the stacktrace

```
2020-01-17 15:54:10 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2020-01-17 15:54:10 - ERROR: relation "predefmapping_seq" does not exist
Position: 17
2020-01-17 15:54:13 - Error adding tags to the DB:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not 
extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149) ~ 
[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157) ~ 
[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164) ~ 
[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:790) ~[hibernate-core- 
5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:768) ~[hibernate-core- 
   5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor118.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~ [na:1.8.0_232]
```

Below is the Entinty class column for which the sequence is added.

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="PREDEFMAPPING_SEQ", sequenceName="PREDEFMAPPING_SEQ",initialValue = 1, allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO ,generator="PREDEFMAPPING_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;
```

Note that this has been tested with db2, oracle and mssql. However for postgres it is giving me the above exception.

The sequence name in postgres db table is "predefmap_seq" and not "PREDEFMAPPING_SEQ" as in the entity.

Most solutions suggest that I  change the Generation strategy to IDENTITY however I wanted  a solution which would be applicable to all (db2, oracle, mssql and postgres)

Comment: What if you use `sequenceName="predefmapping_seq"`? But DB2, Oracle, SQL Server and Postgres all support `identity` columns, so why not use that from Hibernate?

Comment: Changing the sequencename in the db ?

Comment: No, in the annotation (lower case)

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. If you specify a sequence name that is not the right one, obviously that can't work. If the sequence is named predefmap_seq, then use that name in your annotation, or change the name of the sequence so that it matches the one in your annotation.

Comment: Does the user that you use to access the DB have access granted to PREDEFMAPPING_SEQ?